# Bash script to recursive find and convert movies

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, aac, dts

in my large movie collection I would like to search for movies with the primary (first) audio track with DTS coding to be converted to Dolby.

My problem would be the first track I think. My current bash script will list any movie containing a DTS track, but does not specify which track.

```
#!/bin/bash
# My message to create DTS list
find /home/Movies -name '*.mkv' | while read f
do
if mediainfo "$f" | grep A_DTS; then
echo $f 
fi
done
```

After that I would like to run this command

```
ffmpeg -i $f -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k $f
```

or is there a way to move all the audio tracks down and adding the new AAC track?

###Progress

Thanks to @llogan I have finetuned the bash to find the required files.

```
#!/bin/bash
# My DTS conversion script
# credits to llogan

find /Mymovies -name '*.mkv' | while read f
do
 if ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 "$f" | grep dts; then
 echo "$f"
fi
done
```

Now digging into the command I think I may have a working command. Anybody spot a problem?

```
ffmpeg -i $f
      -map 0:v -c:v copy
      -map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 ac3
      -map 0:a:0? -c:a:1 copy
      -map 0:a:1? -c:a:2 copy
      -map 0:a:2? -c:a:3 copy
      -map 0:a:3? -c:a:4 copy
      -map 0:a:4? -c:a:5 copy
      -map 0:a:5? -c:a:6 copy
      -map 0:a:6? -c:a:7 copy
      -map 0:a:7? -c:a:8 copy
      -map 0:a:8? -c:a:9 copy
      -map 0:s? -c copy
      -b:a:0 640k
/tmp/output.mkv
mv $f /home/DTS_BACKUP/
mv /tmp/output.mkv $f
rm /tmp/output.mkv
```

So the end result would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My DTS conversion script
# credits to llogan
find /Mymovies -name '*.mkv' | while read f
do
 if ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 "$f" | grep dts; then

ffmpeg -i $f
          -map 0:v -c:v copy
          -map 0:a:0? -c:a:0 ac3
          -map 0:a:0? -c:a:1 copy
          -map 0:a:1? -c:a:2 copy
          -map 0:a:2? -c:a:3 copy
          -map 0:a:3? -c:a:4 copy
          -map 0:a:4? -c:a:5 copy
          -map 0:a:5? -c:a:6 copy
          -map 0:a:6? -c:a:7 copy
          -map 0:a:7? -c:a:8 copy
          -map 0:a:8? -c:a:9 copy
          -map 0:s? -c copy
          -b:a:0 640k
/tmp/output.mkv
mv $f /home/DTS_BACKUP/
mv /tmp/output.mkv $f
rm /tmp/output.mkv

fi
done
```

Comment: Basically, if the DTS track is the first (main track) I would like to convert it to AAC, make the original DTS track the second etc.

Comment: Use `ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 input.foo` to show the codec name of the 1st audio stream. Use if statement for output of `dts`.

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted in the first place. Now that I get the correct files: how to move all audio tracks one down and insert the AC3 track to become the main audio. Prefer to not lose the original track. But since there are 322 files with main audio DTS .... (and after that I will switch to my DTS-MA....

Comment: Surround all `$f` with double-quotes in case any filenames contain spaces, e.g. `ffmpeg -i "$f"`

Comment: Order via map option: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map -0:a -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:0 ac3 output.mkv` Map everything, except audio, get 1st audio, then all audio.

Comment: Consider using **GNU Parallel** if you have lots of files and a decent CPU. Consider checking the exit status of `ffmpeg` and only moving files if it was successful.

Comment: You can omit `grep` when using an *if statement* and conditions: `if [ "$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 "$f")" = dts ]`

Comment: Tomorrow i will finetune the ffprobe command because it names DTS and DTS-HD to dts. Will have to differentiate between profile and create dts > ac3 and dts-hd to e-ac3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i finetuned the script to seperate dts and dts-hd. I came to the conclusion this was not needed because i cant decode dts-hd to e-ac3 and may as well also encode it to ac3. But i had fun in bash.

Current bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# My DTS conversion script
# credits to llogan

find /MyMovies -name '*.mkv' | while read f
do

function codec_profile {
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=$1 -of csv=p=0 "$f"
}

#first check for audio format
if [ "$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 "$f")" = "dts" ]; then
    if [ "$(codec_profile "profile")" = "DTS" ]; then
      echo "$f" >> dts.txt
      codec_profile "profile" >> dts.txt
      codec_profile "channels" >> dts.txt
      if [ "$(codec_profile "channels")" -gt 5 ]; then
        echo "check" >> dts.txt; else
        echo "stereo" >> dts.txt;
      fi
    else [ "$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=profile -of csv=p=0 "$f")" = "DTS-HD MA" ]; 
      echo "$f" >> dts-hd.txt
      codec_profile "profile" >> dts-hd.txt
      codec_profile "channels" >> dts-hd.txt    
    fi
fi
done
```

I checked the created txt files and the result is spot op. I also tested the command that @llogan gave me and works perfect.

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0 -map -0:a -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k /tmp/output.mkv
```

Last thing to figure out is how to check the exit code on this and replace the text file creation with this command

The idea:

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -map 0 -map -0:a -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -c copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k /tmp/output.mkv
RC=$?
if [ "${RC}" -ne "0" ]; then
    # list error in txt file and move on to next
else
# mv output file to overwrite original file
fi
```

Comment: Is there a way to force a exit error to check this. As you might understand, not really a testing scenario available (could try it on part of the movie selection)

Comment: @llogan running the script as it is (with the encode in place) but after 2 or 3 movies it really slows down. Any clue? Thought at first might be the /tmp so moved the tmp folder within local home. The movies convert flawless at first (and reasonably quick)